# how to access database connection in views in codeigniter 4

Tags: codeigniter-4

I want to execute some query in Views/login.php
I have created database connection in Controller, but i need to execute some sort of queries in Views.
Not able to access it by $this->db->query("") in views, What is the good solution?

Comment: This is a bad idea that violates the premise of the MVC pattern. The controller should get the data from model and pass it to the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note as DFriend mentionned in the comment of this question, this is a bad practice in an MVC pattern. Queries should always be runned in Models that passed data to the Controller which displays those data in Views.**

However if you really want to execute a query into one view you have to initiate your database object before running queries. 
`$this->db` does not exist in your case because your view does not extend a class that has a parameter callled `$db`

```
<?php
    $db = db_connect();
    $query = $db->query('YOUR QUERY');
    //you get result as an array in here but fetch your result however you feel to
    $result = $query->getResultArray();
?>
```

Here you create a database connection, then you run your query with the db object your created.

Comment: Yes, i understand its bad practice to use, in some certain cases, that may usefull.
Your solution works for me, Thank you.
Is the same solution for helper functions ? If we need to execute database query in helper funtions in CI4 ?

Comment: Yes, if you want to run queries you always need to create a database object beforehand. $this->db works in your Controller because it extends the core Controller of Codeigniter which has an attribute creating this database object named $db

Answer (score 0):

You can use the query builder from within a view or any other function by first creating an instance of the database connection by loading the class first $this->load->database() which will give you access to build your queries using the database object as $this->db->query("YOUR RAW QUERY"). Therefore you might do something like

```
    <?php $this->load->database();
          $q = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users");
          $r = $q->result(); // returns an object by default        
    ?>
```

Note: it is not good practice to execute outside your models so only do if you must.